# Inserting records to a table from large collection of csv files

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

In my HDFS, I have a collection of about 350 csv files. Size of each file varies from few KBs to 250Mb. I need to insert the values from these csv files into a table called RECORD. While inserting i also need to refer to some other tables as well (PARAMETER and FRAME_RATE). I have this following query to accomplish this task.

```
 -- create external table for the csv files in hdfs
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEMP_CSV(    
    FRAME_RANK BIGINT,
    FRATE BIGINT,
    SOURCE STRING,
    PARAM STRING,
    RECORDEDVALUE STRING
    )         
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'       
location '/user/bala/output'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="2");


 -- Now insert fresh values into T_RECORD
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE RECORD  
PARTITION(SESSION)
 SELECT DISTINCT         
    TEMP_CSV.F_FRAME_RANK,                          
    PARAMETER.K_ID,
    FRAME_RATE.K_ID,
    CAST(TEMP_CSV.RECORDEDVALUE as FLOAT),        
    split(reverse(split(reverse(TEMP_CSV.INPUT__FILE__NAME),"/")[0]), "[.]")[0] AS SESSION          
    FROM TEMP_CSV , PARAMETER, FRAME_RATE
    WHERE PARAMETER.NAME = TEMP_CSV.PARAM AND  FRAME_RATE.FRATE = TEMP_CSV.FRATE;
```

In my small PoC study, i had about 50 csv files and this query successfully populated the records into RECORD table in about 500seconds with the below configuration

```
Hive-on-spark
spark standalon
6 nodes in the cluster
4 cores per node / 16gb RAM
spark.executor.memory 2g
```

However, when i process 350 files, the query failed with java heap space error in the executor. So, i increased executor.memory to 4g. Failed. I increased executor.memory to 6g. failed. Finally, i increased spark.executor.memory to 12g. Success. But it took about 2 hrs 30min. Increasing spark.executor.memory to 12g resulted in only one executor per node, so, only 6 executor.

When my executor.memory was 6g, this is the log at the time of failure,

```
******
******
2017-06-12 11:59:09,988 Stage-1_0: 101/101 Finished Stage-2_0: 12/12 Fini  shed Stage-3_0: 0(+12,-2)/12 
2017-06-12 11:59:12,997 Stage-1_0: 101/101 Finished Stage-2_0: 12/12 Finished   Stage-3_0: 0(+12,-2)/12 
 2017-06-12 11:59:16,004    Stage-1_0: 101/101 Finished Stage-2_0: 12/12 Finished   Stage-3_0: 0(+12,-2)/12 
 2017-06-12 11:59:19,012    Stage-1_0: 101/101 Finished Stage-2_0: 12/12 Finished   Stage-3_0: 0(+12,-2)/12 
*****
*****
```

In the executor, this is the error log

```
 17/06/12 11:58:36 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(5,[Lscala.Tuple2;@e65f7b8,BlockManagerId(5, bndligpu04, 54618))] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [50 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
at        org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:476)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:505)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:505)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:505)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1801)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:505)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [50 seconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
... 14 more
 17/06/12 11:58:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 115)
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
at org.apache.orc.impl.OutStream.getNewInputBuffer(OutStream.java:109)
at org.apache.orc.impl.OutStream.write(OutStream.java:130)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.writeDeltaValues(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:238)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.writeValues(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:186)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.write(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:772)
at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl$IntegerTreeWriter.writeBatch(WriterImpl.java:1039)
at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl$StructTreeWriter.writeRootBatch(WriterImpl.java:1977)
at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.addRowBatch(WriterImpl.java:2759)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.flushInternalBatch(WriterImpl.java:277)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.addRow(WriterImpl.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcOutputFormat.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:743)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkReduceRecordHandler.processKeyValues(SparkReduceRecordHandler.java:309)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkReduceRecordHandler.processRow(SparkReduceRecordHandler.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveReduceFunctionResultList.processNextRecord(HiveReduceFunctionResultList.java:49)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveReduceFunctionResultList.processNextRecord(HiveReduceFunctionResultList.java:28)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveBaseFunctionResultList$ResultIterator.hasNext(HiveBaseFunctionResultList.java:95)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:41)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions$$anonfun$foreachAsync$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(AsyncRDDActions.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions$$anonfun$foreachAsync$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(AsyncRDDActions.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 17/06/12 11:58:36     ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-1,5,main]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
at org.apache.orc.impl.OutStream.getNewInputBuffer(OutStream.java:109)
at org.apache.orc.impl.OutStream.write(OutStream.java:130)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.writeDeltaValues(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:238)
```

My questions are:-

1. Is there a scope to optimize the query?
2. Any other spark/hive configuration that can handle this challenge?
3. Is there a way to tell Hive to process, lets say, 50 files after another 50?

Any  help / information to fix this issue will be useful. One more info, the 'SELECT' statement works and i could see the results in my hue browser. When I try to INSERT the information collected by 'SELECT' is when the query breaks.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging into the logs and the tables itself, I did the following

1. I removed the 'clustering' of RECORD table. Earlier, RECORD was bucketed (12 numbers) which created 12 tasks in the second stage. In order to increase this number, I removed the buckets. Now, it has created 273 tasks. I still don't know the reasons behind it. But, with executor memory 4gb, this config worked.
2. I moved to spark-on-yarn configuration. This has improved the performance. Now, I am able to finish the query in 35 m.

Still, I see that there could be a scope or two to optimize the query. I will try with join.

Answer (score -1):

You can try increasing the executor cores for this job.

The executor cores are the number of Concurrent tasks that an executor can run. The worker cores - to make the workers run are the “CPU cores”.

In Spark there is the option to set the amount of CPU cores when starting a slave which defines the total CPU cores to allow Spark applications to use on the machine only on worker. Default is: use all available cores

The command to start Spark would be something like this:
`./sbin/start-all.sh --cores 2`

Or you can try with `--executor-cores 2`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, But i wonder how --executor-cores=2 will be the right fix. Because, when, only one process is running in one core with all the 6gb available, it fails. Running one more process to share with 6gb should again fail. Right? I can nevertheless give a try.